# Fetch products by category in Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I'm using Woocomerce for my wordpress shopping cart. I'm connect my Android App to my Wordpress database through Woocommerce REST API. I need to get products by category on my App. There is no provision in the REST API to fetch product by category.

I tried by using the filter attribute:

```
https://example.com/wc-api/v1/products?filter[product_cat]=gedgets&consumer_key=ck_9354534x&consumer_secret=cs_dx7345345
```

This is return me all the products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [WooThemes/WooCommerce documentation](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce/rest-api/#get-products) you need to use `filters`, like you say, only you appear to have the filter name wrong.

Try:

```
https://mysite.com/wc-api/v1/products?filter[categories]=gedgets&consumer_key=ck_9354534x&consumer_secret=cs_dx7345345
```

`categories` is the name of the field returned by the API, so that should be what you use.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Unfortunately it also returns all products.

Answer (score 12):

In this case you should use the filters...

however, It worked for me :

> http://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?**category=16**

the 16 is a sample of category id...

Comment: Thank you very much, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

- You Need **WP Rest API** plugin for this API
- Create Credentials in woocommmerce->Settings->Advance you find REST API link after tabs
- add key and use Consumer Key and Consumer Secret for type OAuth 1.0 authorization header and use this API.

  http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?category={ID}

I used this API and it's perfectly working

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is trying to achieve this in the future with v2 of the Woo REST API, this is how it's done:

`https://${baseUrl}/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=${categoryId}`

And if you only have the slug of the category, as opposed to the id, you can first:

`https://${baseUrl}/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?slug=${categorySlug}`

Answer (score 2):

use filter[category] insted of filter[categories]

```
https://ursite.com/wc-api/v1/products?filter[category]=gedgets&consumer_key=ck_9354534x&consumer_secret=cs_dx7345345
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Use the slug as parameter value for category. You can also add other filters, I added a limit filter in addition to category and it works great

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking products filter by multiple categories id use below API endpoint:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=20,30
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a typo in your filtering?
I noticed that it says [categories]=gedgets but should it be [categories]=gadgets instead?

I am trying to figure out Woocommerce REST API myself and I noticed that if I type something wrong in the filter, it returns all results.

Comment: No, the slug is same 'gedgets'. Spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Woocommerce REST API, They don't have a solution(filters) for this issue. [woocommerce github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6241)

Hope they will add this feture in their next release.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to the github page, this feature is not yet available. However, if you look  here: http://justgeeks.in/woocommerce-rest-api-fetch-products-category/ you will find what you need to filter by category slug...